# How do I run a .bas file

Tags: basic

I want to start coding in BASIC. However I do not know how to run a .bas file.

If someone could help me it would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: It is usually better to ask a new question than recycle an old one when the topics are completely different. It has bigger chance to be answered.

Comment: Find an IDE and load the .bas then start it from the run menu, try the QB64 project at www.qb64.net

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SmallBASIC](http://smallbasic.github.io/pages/download.html), a BASIC interpreter, which can be downloaded for Windows [here](http://smallbasic.github.io/pages/download.html), and for Linux [here](http://smallbasic.github.io/pages/download.html). Also, if you're looking for an Android app that will run it, you can download it [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.smallbasic).